# Remove space when phone not navigation bar in app android

Tags: android

I want to remove the marked section of space

[image]

I'm writing an android application but if I run on my phone without a 3-way navigator, it will be replaced by a space. How can I remove that void?

Comment: set your parent layout's height to match_parent

Comment: you means when you run on phone without soft-keys and like galaxy phone with physical button? paste your layout xml too

Comment: @tahsinRupam http://imgur.com/a/MZJhJ

Comment: @EliasFazel codepad.org/c9g3AVJL

Comment: @LêTrungĐô Try change ListView height to match_parent and remove the layout_weight. Tell me both results you get with or without navigation bar, I'll assist you further.

Comment: there is some 0dp height change all of them to wrap_content.